# Why does my browser refetch an image that is in cache

Tags: javascript, reactjs, google-chrome, caching, preload

Basically I have a React app that uses a lot of images. In order for it to run smoothly, I first fetched every image I will need so that it is saved in cache and can be displayed quicker. I expect that when I do need to use those images in my components, they can just be loaded from memory and don't have to be fetched again. However, this is not the case for some reason. As you can see below, the same image is fetched twice (first during initialization and second during component mount). By the way, the images have the same name and are fetched from the same server that's also hosting the app. I don't understand why my browser (Chrome) is not recognizing the fact that it has downloaded those images already. I thought it auto-detects if a file is in cache already? Is there a way to check if a file is in cache?

[image]

Comment: Have you checked what the `size` column in the network panel has to say? It should say `(memory cache)` or `(disk cache)` there, if a resource was fetched from the cache.

Comment: (Also make sure you don't have the `Disable Cache` option enabled when checking on this in dev tools.)

Comment: Nope, it does not say memory cache or disk cache. Appears that it was downloaded again.

Comment: Does this have to do with CORS? I see that I made some other request from a third-party API and it was accessed from memory cache. Does the fact that everything I'm using is from the same server have to do with anything?

Comment: No, don't see how CORS should be relevant. The URL you have shown, with those GET parameters - is that actually mapping onto some static file, or is the response script generated?

Comment: Should be a static file. Here's my code: ```app.get("/animation", (req, res) => {
    res.sendFile(path.resolve(__dirname, `./public/animations/${req.query.dirName}/${req.query.dirName}-${String(req.query.index).padStart(2, "0")}.png`))
})```

Comment: Okay, but it still gets served via your application. Check what response headers regarding caching are send.

Comment: My cache headers are ```Cache-Control: public, max-age=0```. This means that the cache cannot be reused right? Can I fix it with ```res.setHeader('Cache-Control', "public, max-age=1800")```? EDIT: It worked!